# JQuery Regex want to remove commas from string

Tags: jquery, regex

I have a string like

```
Andrew,Lucy,,David,Tess,
```

I want to remove `,,` after Lucy and also a comma from the end of the string so the end results i need would be

```
Andrew,Lucy,David,Tess
```

is there any way to achieve this in jQuery?

Comment: `.replace(/,,|,\s/,"")`

Comment: Thanks zer00ne but it doesn't work. Here are the results
AndrewLucy,,David,Tess,

Comment: I forgot the flag `str.replace(/(,{2,})|(,$)/g, "")`

Comment: *"in jQuery"* - jQuery is not a string manipulation library. (Which is why none of the answers used it.)

Answer (score 2):

This is a working regex:

```
/,+(?=,|$)/g
```

[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hL4mD6/1)

Remove redundant commas followed by a comma or end of line. If you apply this to multiple lines add `m` (multiline flag) after the closing slash too (otherwise `$` matches only at the very end of the text instead of at each newline).

**Code Demo**

```js
// Add /i at bottom to make the regex it case insensitive
var re = /,+(?=,|$)/g; 

var tests = ['Andrew,Lucy,,David,Tess,','Andrew,,,,Lucy,,,David,Tess,,,'].reverse();
var m;

while( t = tests.pop() ) {
    document.write('"' + t + '" => <font color="green">' + t.replace(re,'') + '</font><br/>');
}
```

Comment: What about `,,Andrew` cases ? ;)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: I strictly follow the "Don't add unrequested feature" XP principle: :P

Answer (score 2):

Use Positive Lookahead `?=`

```js
var str = "Andrew,Lucy,,David,Tess,";
str = str.replace(/,(?=,+|$)/g, "");
console.log( str ); // Andrew,Lucy,David,Tess
```

> stop at comma `,` than *lookahead `?=`* for it's followed by:
>   `,+` one or more commas
>   `|` or it's at end of string `$`

**Important**

Most probably you'll need to take care for cases when the string **starts with one or more commas**, than simply append `^,+|` to your regex:

```js
var str = ",,Andrew,Lucy,,David,Tess,,";
str = str.replace(/^,+|,(?=,+|$)/g, "");
console.log( str ); // Andrew,Lucy,David,Tess
```

or respectively `/^,+|,(?=,+)|,+$/g`

Comment: I think this is a perfect answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. Really appreciate your efforts.

Did something like this.
It worked

```
var your_string = 'Andrew, Lucy,, David, Tess,';
newstr=your_string.replace(',,', ',');

your_string1 = newstr.replace(/[,]$/,'');
```

first i removed double commas and then i removed comma from the end

Comment: Isn't `,+` bulletproofer than `,,,,,,` ? I realize that the requirement was `,,` but hey yo.

Comment: You can also chain it: `var newstr=your_string.replace(',,', ',').replace(/[,]$/,'');`

Comment: If you pass a string as the first argument to `.replace()` it will only replace the first match. Is that what you want?

Comment: The brackets in `/[,]$/` are unnecessary. `/,$/` will suffice. Not sure what are all the cases you need to support, but for more variants of `,` positions -  this solution is insufficient

Answer (score -1):

Or You can simply use `.replace()`

```
var str = "Andrew,Lucy,,David,Tess,";
var res = str.replace(",,", ",").replace(/,\s*$/, "");
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/amarsingh/cgwa1o82/)

Comment: @DarrenSweeney : My bad. I did not notice that in question. done editing

Answer (score -1):

Without a regex :

```js
var str = "Andrew,Lucy,,David,Tess,";
var res = str.split(",");
res = res.filter(Boolean);
res = res.join(",");
console.log(res);
```

With a regex and replace function():

```js
var str = "Andrew,Lucy,,David,Tess,";
var res = str.replace(/,,|,$/g, function(x){
  return x == ",," ? ",": "";});
console.log(res);
```